# Retrieving bytes from scatterlist

Tags: c, linux-kernel

Given

int *text = "string_test";

We know that

```
sg_set_buf(struct scatterlist *sg, const void *buf, unsigned int buflen)
```

include/linux/scatterlist.h

If we do

```
  sg_set_buf(req.src, text, strlen(text));
```

How do we retrieve `text` bytes from the scatterlist?

Comment: yes. I had. It didn't show much direct example. I can't retrieve it from kernel space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could solve the problem using:

```
char *buf;
buf = sg_virt (sg);
```